# pyahk python setup.py egg_info with error code 1 error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to install pyahk on python 3 and I'm getting the error "python setup.py egg_info" with error code 1

I've looked at other posts with this error on stackoverflow and other sites.  I've tried the suggestions others have suggested but it doesn't seem to work.

I expected by using the pip install pyahk command that it would install the module pyahk.  But what I'm getting is the error code above.  As far as I know, pyahk should work with python 3, how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install the library from the source? https://pyahk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installation